# Sails.js time as model's attribute

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I wanted to ask, can anyone point me to any example of using 'time' as an attribute of a model? It's possible according to documentation http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models , but I can't find any examples, and I'd like to know what type is it representing, cause I don't know 'time' type in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time` is deprecated and should not be used in new Sails projects.  It was an alias for `date` and `dateTime`, which are still valid.  We'll go ahead and remove `time` from the documentation, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sails-mongo you most likely want `'datetime'` type. Which will look like `ISODate("2014-04-03T07:00:00Z")` in your mongo database.

...And of course a Date() object of the JS end.

hope that helps.

Comment: How to store a time value in a `DateTime` attribute? I mean no to pass the whole format value `("2014-04-03T07:00:00Z")` in the request, just send something like `("07:18:22")`.